# Keras Embedding layer - ValueError: Error when checking input: expected to have 2 dimensions, but got (39978, 20, 20)

Tags: python, keras, nlp, keras-layer

I am trying to create a LSTM/GRU model in keras to categorise given articles in one of the 4 classes.

```
input > embedding layer > LSTM/GRU layer > [context vector] > Dense(softmax activation) > output class
```

In the training input data there are 39978 articles each article has 20 sentences and each sentence has 20 words. As for the target variable there are 4 target classes.

`x_train.shape` is `(39978, 20, 20)` and

`y_train.shape` is `(39978, 4)`

`embedding_matrix.shape` is `(27873, 100)` embedding_matrix is created on vocabulary with **glove.6B.100d.txt**

I am trying to create a sequential model like below

```py
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index.keys()) # 27873
MAX_SENT_LENGTH = 20

model = Sequential()
embedding_dimentations = embedding_matrix.shape[1]
e = Embedding(vocab_size, 
              embedding_dimentations, 
              weights=[embedding_matrix], 
              input_length=MAX_SENT_LENGTH, 
              trainable=False)
model.add(e)

model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(embedding_dimentations, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25)))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

on above model if i do a fit

```py
batch_size = 128
epochs = 3

print('Training.....')
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=.2)
```

I am getting following error

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_6_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (39978, 20, 20)

I tried specifying input shape tuple in Embedding() but its not working. Can someone point me in right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```py
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index.keys()) # 27873
MAX_SENT_LENGTH = 20
embedding_dimentations = embedding_matrix.shape[1]

model = Sequential()

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(20, 20))
x1 = Reshape((400,))(encoder_inputs)
x2 = Embedding(vocab_size, 
              embedding_dimentations, 
              weights=[embedding_matrix], 
              input_length=400, 
              trainable=False)(x1)

# should use Bidirectional GRU
encoder = GRU(embedding_dimentations, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h = encoder(x2)

predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(encoder_outputs)

model = Model(inputs=encoder_inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Used Reshape layer before the Embedding layer to get the data into correct shape. This approach is working for me.